# Is it possible to mark a question in order to be notified of the answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, notifications

Is it possible to mark a question in order to be notified of the answers? The aim here is only to have a quick way to be informed of the answers, without taking any kind of action on the question.

Comment: @David thanks. But I am more or less happy with the edit : the words "any kind of appreciation" was about "I dont want to say I like (or not) the question", just about "I want to follow the answer". So favorite feature is not exactly what I expected. But it is convenient enough. So this comment was just FYI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the [favorite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/278094) feature does what you are looking for, or as close as SE offers.

After clicking the little star under the vote buttons on any question, it will get added to your [favorite list](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/24625/lemon?tab=favorites). Any time anything changes, or a new answer gets added a little blue box with how many changes will show up there.
[image: favorite link on user page]

Then just sort your favorite list by "*activity*", and the most recent changed question will be at the top.

---

If you are into RSS, then you can click the [image: question feed link]
link at the bottom of the page on any question. That feed will include, and update for any answers.